# Using Heroku CI, tests are running on heroku for every branch - how can i limit it to only my main branch?

Tags: heroku

Looking to save some time, I deployed to heroku which i've used in the past for a personal app.

Setting up the built in CI/CD pipeline for heroku I noticed that its running tests for every single branch. I only want it to run on the master/main branch

is there an ability to limit the tests to only a specific branch? I know i can limit which branch goes to production deployment, but im not seeing any controls for limiting testing.

I dont want to pay for CPU performance being consumed on heroku for every branch that receives a git commit, I only want them to run to confirm the master branch has tests passing.

Master branch automatically rolls into production

Comment: Don't you want to verify that your tests pass before merging into your main branch? Tests should _prevent_ errors, not let you know that something is broken after the fact.

Comment: @chris Peer code review takes place prior to merging into the main branch.

Comment: That's not the same thing. I strongly suggest you reconsider your plan to let feature branches get merged without CI.

Comment: That’s not what I’m asking, I’m asking is there a way to turn it off for other branches and cut down the cost. The project is not for a business it’s for my own volunteer project I’m paying for.

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking, otherwise I'd have posted this as an answer.